# How do I manipulate a DOM Element before it is even added to the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**The code:**
https://codepen.io/furkancodes-the-typescripter/pen/QWdYgzp?editors=1010

**Preface:**
I have been trying to code this Library app, I am using innerHTML to write all the css when the book is added to the library. It works, but when I implemented the "delete", it deletes the row when clicked on the delete icon, however, since I set the delete to "display" which is half of the screen, wherever you click, the "book deleted" error comes up and I know the reason why, it is because I set it to "display"(which is the contents of the library!)

There comes is problematic and confusing part for me;

row.innerHTML creates a div class called "book" and it contains the all of the book information and displays it on the "display" however, I only to select "book" class and I write;

```
const book = document.querySelector('.book');

book.addEventListener
// and here I add the codes to delete that book row
```

but book.AddEvent always return "null" and it makes sense because it is not there in the first place...

**The main question and solution to my problem too:**
That is why I Am trying to learn about **how do I touch a class before even it is initiliazed.** Because I want to select that "book" class which holds all the information, but I just can't.

**Some other thing I Will try if all else fails:**
Last thing I thought but did not do was ditching all of the row.innerHTML element, and writing and appending each of the elements in my book library such as AUthor, title etc and appending them one by one. But this will take a while.

Sorry for the long post, I hope I made myself clear and I would appreciate if I gotta fix something in my thought-process.

Comment: You probably think about using an `array` to hold your book collection and think about iterating over the array using each iteration to fill a template used for display. What you're doing here is basic `CRUD` operations.

Comment: Yeah, I never knew what CRUD was, but seems like this is what I have been doing. I will re-write the whole code base with an array. Actually, I started with an array but got sidetracked I think.

Comment: Now, I store all of my books in myLibrary array. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. you are trying get `.book` element before it's added into new `row`
2. you are using `document.querySelector()`, which will search entire document and return first found instance of the query. Instead use `row.querySelector()`, which will only search current book (obviously after 1. is fixed)

So your `addBookToLibrary()` should look something like this:

```
  addBookToLibrary(book) {
    const list = document.querySelector('.display-lib');
    const row = document.createElement('th');

 
    row.innerHTML = `
  <div class="book"> 
   <div class="title">Title: ${book.title}</div>
   <p class="author">Author: ${book.author}</p>
  <p class="pages">Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
  <p class="pages">Notes: ${book.notes}</p>
  <span class="read_toggle_label">Mark as read:</span>
    
         <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
     
  <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
  </div>
  `;
   const bookTh = row.querySelector('.book');



    list.appendChild(row);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take a deep look into this.

Comment: I have managed to fix it, thanks for pointing out. I will update the code as how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 addBookToLibrary(book) {
            const shelf = document.querySelector('#book-list');
            const row = document.createElement('th');


            row.innerHTML = `
            <div class="book"> 
            <div class="title">Title: ${book.title}</div>
             <p class="author">Author: ${book.author}</p>
            <p class="pages">Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
            <p class="pages">Notes: ${book.notes}</p>
            <span class="read_toggle_label">Mark as read:</span>
            <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
     
            <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
            </div>
            `;

        const dlt = row.querySelector('.delete');
        dlt.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                 //first get the UI 
                 const ui = new UI();
                 ui.deleteBook(e.target);
                 ui.showAlertDelete('book removed', 'success');
        })

        shelf.appendChild(row);
        }
```